# meta tag text/html;CHARSET=x-mac-roman

Tags: html, editor

Which editor adds this to the HTML files it creates? It is pretty obviously a Mac program.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;CHARSET=x-mac-roman">
```

I have a page that let's users upload an HTML file, and HtmlAgility chokes on this...

I'm just curious as to where this tag comes from, as I've never seen it..

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from BillGates' ripoff Word when it runs on MacOS and the user writes a Word document then chooses 'Save as WebPage'.  The stupid thing is that the web page produced shows up beautifully in FireFox but Gates' own IE mucks up all the accents (I've been struggling with trying to iron out the problem for text written in French).